# Victory Chart style the x-axis and the y-axis label independently

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, victory-charts

I am using Victory chart and I have roughly the following code

```
<VictoryChart domainPadding={30} {...commonProps}>
        <VictoryBar
          data={props.data}
          {...labelProps}
        />
  </VictoryChart>
```

I used tickLabels style {angle: 45}, however this is applied internally to both x and y axis , I want the tilted text only for the x-axis but as you can see it, it has also affected the y-axis, how can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try specifying both axis in component and apply style only to one of them

```
<VictoryChart domainPadding={10}>
  <VictoryBar
    data={sampleData}
  />
  <VictoryAxis dependentAxis
    tickValues={[1, 2, 3, 4,5]}
  />
  <VictoryAxis
    tickValues={[1, 2, 3, 4,5]}
    style={{ tickLabels: {angle :45}}}
  />
</VictoryChart>
```

Comment: When I use `angle: 45` my labels get offset incorrectly from the tick marks on the chart so I want to push them back over to line up, do you know how I would do that? Your code implies it should just work but it does not.

Comment: @ctrl-zpls - i used `transform: 'translate(-20, 10)'` after my `angle` property

Comment: When I used the `{angle: 90, transform: 'translate(-20, 10)}`, my labels for X-axis getting clipped at bottom. I also tried giving absolute height to component but no solution. Any insights on that?